# Add new row to database depending on number of textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using windows forms - I have x amount of textboxes, depending of if the user specifies that x = 2,3,4 or 5 is the amount of rows which will need to be added to my database. As the user will only add information to x amount of text boxes -  so far I have got the first half of the code, I'm just not sure how to implement the textboxes sections using loops...

```
    for (int x = 0; x <= TextBox.Count - 1; x++)// This is where I struggle for each textbox
    {
        MAcon.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into [Parts Inventroy]([Part ID],[Part Name],[Product Family ID] values(@PartID, @PartName, @ProductFamilyID)", MAcon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductFamilyID", pfName.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MAcon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you learn about `for` loops?

Comment: As @mjwills said, Loop through your controls. Maybe consider using DataGrids for adding rows instead a variable amount of controls. Looks better and is easier to handle when editing or deleting.

Comment: Is this windows forms or ASP.Net?

Comment: it is windows forms

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I understand your question correctly.

In your application, user provides an input (say X). Based on that number you create X number of textboxes. Then from all these textboxes, you take the user input and put that in the database.

If above is correct, here is how you can achieve:

```
// Private member to hold the use created textboxes
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();

// Sample code for your actual method where textboxes are added
public void UserAddsTextBoxes(int userInput)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < userInput; index++)
    {
        TextBox current = new TextBox();
        Controls.Add(current);

        // Also add it to our list for later
        textboxes.Add(current);
    }
}

public void OnSavingData()
{
    textboxes.ForEach(x =>
    {
        MAcon.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into [Parts Inventroy]([Part ID],[Part Name],[Product Family ID] values(@PartID, @PartName, @ProductFamilyID)", MAcon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductFamilyID", x.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MAcon.Close();
    });
}
```